# i want to send data from one view to another Laravel view

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

> i have two views, view-1 and view-2.

- **view-1** has form, which will store data temporary.
- i want to get data from **view-1** and send it to **view-2**, which has user profile, where temporary data from **view-1** will be shown.
- how we can achieve it in Laravel, i know we can store data in SQL
  and then fetch it, but how to do it without storing to SQL.

**my code:**
view: 1

```
<form >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" >Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="sdate" class="form-control">
    <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Add date" >
  </div>
</form>
```

view 2 Controller:

```
public function report2($id)
{
$teacher = Teacher::teacher($id);
return View('teachers.report2' ,compact('teacher','today','sdate'));
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('teachers/{id}/report2', 'TeachersController@report2');
```

Comment: get the request data and pass the request data using compact

Comment: i guess we can't get request data with controller; public function report2($id)

Comment: we can get using request()->all();

Comment: both views have different controllers.

Comment: not a problem please describe in deep     dd(request()->all());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use session, for example in view1 you pass variable of date do this on your controller of view 1

```
session(['sdate' => $request->sdate]);
```

and then  you can get the value of the session in your controller or view by calling this

```
$date = session('sdate');
```

further reading see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session)

Comment: can you please tell me where to write; session(['sdate' => $request->sdate]);
in my code above. do we need to submit form also?

Comment: when i add your code in my controller; public function report2($id),
i get error id missing.

Comment: put session(['sdate' => $request->sdate]); on your form's action on view1, then you can call $date = session('sdate'); on the view2 directly

Comment: i added; session(['sdate' => $request->sdate]); but when i click on submit it is not opening required view.

Answer (score -1):

i was able to do it using simple php;
in view 1 i added this code:

```
<form action="report2"  method="get">
  Date: <input type="text" name="today" placeholder="Date of Birth"  class="datepicker form-control"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Laravel view 2:

```
<?php echo $_GET["today"]; ?><br>
```