# showing data in selective bootstrap pills

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i have 3 bootstrap pills, i want to show some data in pill 2 and pill 3 but not in pill 1 how i can achieve that.
i can achieve this if i type data in both pills, but how to achieve this by writing data only once.

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#pill1">Pill 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Pill2">Pill 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Pill3">Pill 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="pill1" class="tab-pane fade">
     <h3>Pill 1</h3>
      <p>Pill 1 data</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Pill2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Pill 2</h3>
      <p>Pill2 data</p>
      <p> THIS DATA SHOULD BE IN PILL 2 AND PILL 3 ONLY</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Pill3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Pill 3</h3>
      <p>Pill 3 data</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to do and where is data. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: suppose it's text which i added in question.

Comment: you can use a variable and set what value you want. And then use that variable (echo) wherever you want.

Comment: in actual scenario i have Form to fill user information.

Comment: I think you can use session. Set a session variable and use it any page by calling session variable. I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: same suggestion was given in this answer;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56109136/10697521
but i couldn't follow it, can you please check.

Comment: I will make an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set session variable in blade

```
Session::set('variableName', $value); // $value = what value you want to store
```

And to get session variable in blade

```
Session::get('variableName');
```

Comment: i want to fetch data from one view, and use it in another view.

Comment: then set the variable in one and use it in another view.

Comment: and for syntax go through official documentations

Comment: can you please edit your answer for; set the variable in one and use it in another view

Comment: i need to type anything in controller? $value is??

Comment: that is what you want to store

Comment: i want to type some value in text box, and when i click on open next page i want that value there.